# Android: how to expand and collapse cardView size in RecyclerView

Tags: android

I need to expand and collapse `CardView` size in `RecyclerView` at run time.
I use `RecyclerView` to display a list and `CardView` as `RecyclerView` Item.
As I am new to this concept please help me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have expand on run time. like this,

Setting my view on `onCreateView()`

```
descriptionCardView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver
    .OnPreDrawListener() {
@Override
public boolean onPreDraw() {
    detailProductDescription.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
    // save the full height
    descriptionViewFullHeight = detailProductDescription.getHeight();

    // initially changing the height to min height
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = descriptionCardView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = (int) getActivity().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen
            .product_description_min_height);
    descriptionCardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    return true;
 }
});
```

and onClickingcardview

```
@OnClick(R.id.detail_product_description)
void onProductDescriptionClicked(View view) {
    toggleProductDescriptionHeight();
}
```

i am setting CardView Height to expand and collapse.

```
private int descriptionViewFullHeight;    
private void toggleProductDescriptionHeight() {

    int descriptionViewMinHeight = (int) getActivity().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen
            .product_description_min_height);
    if (descriptionCardView.getHeight() == descriptionViewMinHeight) {
        // expand
        ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(descriptionCardView.getMeasuredHeightAndState(),
                descriptionViewFullHeight);
        anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = descriptionCardView.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.height = val;
                descriptionCardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        });
        anim.start();
    } else {
        // collapse
        ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(descriptionCardView.getMeasuredHeightAndState(),
                descriptionViewMinHeight);
        anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = descriptionCardView.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.height = val;
                descriptionCardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        });
        anim.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is detailProductDescription in this cardview. where is it initialized

Comment: It's a variable (like Card view) , you can inflate your view by find view id, any where and decide it's variable name.