# CardView resize animation

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to make a view using CardView with resising animation like here:

[resize animation](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_8/material_ext_publish/0B14F_FSUCc01QVYxZ3NITnJfUjA/Aware_02_MoveAway-v2.webm)

It should contain only a header in small version and more details after resizing. I guess I have to put Cards into a CoordinatorLayout, but how to animate them? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31911684/android-how-to-expand-and-collapse-cardview-size-in-recyclerview