# Expand/Collapse CardView in Android

Tags: android, material-design, android-cardview

I was scrolling through the Material Design card [guidelines](https://material.google.com/components/cards.html#cards-content) and they discuss at length the ability to expand/collapse a card. Hence, I was wondering if this behavior is supported using any native android library? I know there's [the AAkira ExpandableLayout](https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout) library but that's not native and does not support CardView.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [FoldingCell](https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell-android) library

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31911684/android-how-to-expand-and-collapse-cardview-size-in-recyclerview